# Left UK with unpaid payday loan and unpaid mobile contacts, now want to apply for another student visa

Tags: united-kingdom

I was an international student in the UK and had left the UK in 2014 February as an international student. At the time of leaving UK i had unpaid payday loan and couple of mobile and land line contacts on my name. The payday loan companies tried to contact me for sometime and after that they had sold the debt to a third party, and they also tried to contact me. But i ignored all of their contacts. Now my query is that will i be able to apply for the UK Tier 4 student visa and whether i will be arrested in the airport?
I will be eagerly waiting to get the reply.

Comment: You should pay your debts whether or not you face arrest.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about legal implications and immigration

Answer (score 2):

Private sector debt is something to be settled between you and that party. UK law enforcement doesnt have anything to do operationally for such third party. 
As such, if your Visa is approved and you don't have any pending arrest warrant I cannot imagine any situation where you would be arrested.
Unless you have knowingly committed fraud and this is proven in a court of law, you cannot be sent to prison for failing to pay your debts.

All that being said, it seems that outstanding debt or previous credit report are not points taken into consideration when applying for a T4 Student Visa. [1](https://visaguide.world/europe/uk-visa/student/)

You should also take into consideration that once a default is recorded on your credit profile, you can't have it removed before the six years are up in the UK so you that's something you should definitely take into consideration when moving back into the UK as you now want to.

Comment: "you cannot be sent to prison for failing to pay your debts" anymore.